# Django model conditionally based on two abstract classes

Tags: python, django, django-models, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have more of a conceptual question, but with practical implications.
In a Django 4.1.x app, I have one `owner` class which can be either a `person` or an `organization`, but never both together.
These two classes doesn't need to be registered in the database, only the `owner` has to:

```py
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        verbose_name=_("First name"),
        null=False,
    )
    # other person attributes, e.g.:
    surname = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        verbose_name=_("Surname"),
        null=False,
    )
    street = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        verbose_name=_("Street"),
        null=False,
    )
    country = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        verbose_name=_("Country"),
        null=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

class Organization(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        verbose_name=_("Full name"),
        null=False,
    )
    # other organization attributes, e.g.:
    register_identifier = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        verbose_name=_("Register identifier"),
        null=False,
    )
    street = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        verbose_name=_("Street"),
        null=False,
    )
    country = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        verbose_name=_("Country"),
        null=False,
    )
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

Whatever the `owner` instance is, it must have a `name` attribute:
In the case of a person, the owner's name has to be the `first_name` and in case of an organization, the `full_name`.

Also, if an `owner` object is an instance of a `Person`: I only want to expose those other attributes of `Person`. Same goes if `owner` is an instance of an `Organization`.

I certainly miss some concepts here / maybe I'm not looking in the right direction, but  how to build the `owner` model based on a type of "conditional or parametrized inheritance", let's say?

Please, note that the `Person` class is also used to build other objects, such as e.g. `designer` or `painter` in the entire app. Same goes for `Organization` which serves as the basis for different types of organizations. Hence their `abstract = True`.

#### EDIT

As suggested in the comment bellow by SamSparx, I've tried to use the appealing "[proxy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#proxy-models)" concept. For that, I needed to remove the `abstract = True` flag from both `Person` and `Organization` classes and setting `proxy = True` within the `Owner` class. But then, when trying to `makemigrations` it says:

```
TypeError: Proxy model 'Owner' has more than one non-abstract model base class.
```

```
class Owner(Organisation, Person):

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

This is expected as the doc says:
Base class restrictions

> A proxy model must inherit from exactly one non-abstract model class. You can’t inherit from multiple non-abstract models as the proxy model doesn’t provide any connection between the rows in the different database tables. A proxy model can inherit from any number of abstract model classes, providing they do not define any model fields. A proxy model may also inherit from any number of proxy models that share a common non-abstract parent class.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#base-class-restrictions

So it doesn't really help at the moment.

Comment: Is there a reason that proxy classes couldn't be used here?   (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#proxy-models). So long as all your children are using the same model, you can add properties and methods specific to the proxy classes and even chain inheritence eg, Owner -> Person -> Painter

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't know about that. After some attempts, I face plenty of `field clashes` errors + another tiny detail: what if my `Artist` class is fully based on the `Person` class, but it has some extra fields which can't belong to the `Person` class, such as `ArtistType` or `ArtistGallery` for example? Adding specific fields raises: `(models.E017) Proxy model 'Artist' contains model fields.` This is weird to me at this point. I also tried to set `proxy=True` in the `Owner` class but one can apparently not proxy a class inheriting from 2 non-abstract classes.

Comment: The idea is more you set a base 'normal' Owner class (which has a table), and then create proxy=true child classes off that eg, class Person(Owner):, and Organisation(Owner). These child classes use the same table but have their own properties and methods. You are right you can't add fields to child classes...though if children with that requirement are rare you can add them to the base Owner and handle it through the child class's save() method.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of possible approaches, but they have tradeoffs. A lot will depend on how important it is for your classes to all use the same table. As a rule of thumb, if a non-abstract model needs new fields, it needs a new table.

Abstract classes:

These are useful as archetypes, but you can't combine them and then only have one abstract class 'active'. If Org and Person are both abstract classes used to create Owner, then Owner will have all of the fields in both classes.

Any non abstract class will need its own table, eg, children of Owner or other classes with the Person abstract.

Proxy classes:

This is basically your option for using only one table. Using this method you can create separate child classes for your class AND its children all using the same table, with each class having distinct methods and properties. However, they must all share the same fields. If only occasional children need new fields, they might be able to be added to the base class without too much overhead, and handled or ignored via the respective proxy class's methods.